# Concatenate parameter of type string with '%' symbol in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to match strings in SQL using `LIKE`.

In my case I'm passing parameter to function of type string (say Ex: myText)

I want to match all the string preceding with myText and ending with any text

Ex: `myText='001'`

If I have string `001002,001005,0012,` it should match all and return values

I'm trying as follows:

```
SELECT Text
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Text LIKE myText + '%'
```

Comment: SQL uses `||` to concatenate string values, not `+`.

Comment: Hi @VijayKumar, which db are you using?

Comment: Hello @Andy i'm using Oracle database

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name  that suggestion worked for me. cheers

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator is for the addition of numbers. Text concatenation uses the `||` operator:

```
SELECT Text
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Text LIKE myText || '%'
```

or

```
SELECT Text
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Text LIKE CONCAT( myText, '%' )
```